# Can I use routing key for binding to exchange when using RabbitMQ consistent hashing?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, publish-subscribe, messaging, consistent-hashing

I need to achieve pub/sub messaging where one publisher publishes an event to a single consistent hashing exchange and other subscribers use routing key (event name) to indicate interest in a specific event. When using consistent hashing plugin routing key is used as weight value when queue binds to exchange. Is there any way to use routing keys while still using consistent hashing exchange? or my topology of exchange/queue needs to be changed somehow?